# Python spark : How to parellelize Spark Dataframe compute using spark in databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a python code that compute dataframe in parellelize  using the library: **multiprocessing.pool**

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
```

#### Here is how I created my dataframe

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 1.,
                    'B': pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'C': pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype='float32'),
                    'D': [3,4,2,5],
                    'E': pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train"]),
                    'F': 'foo'})
```

#### Here is how I parralize the compute of a dataframe

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func, n_cores=1):  
  df_split = np.array_split(df, n_cores) # split dataframe into n_cores
  pool = Pool(n_cores) # load cpu cores numbers
  df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split),ignore_index=True) #we collect all the data 
  pool.close() # end of proccesing
  pool.join() # join data 
  return df # return the dataframe
```

#### Here is the function to process on dataframe column

```
def TrouverLesTest(x):
    if(x=='test'):
        return True
    elif(x=='train'):
        return False
```

#### Here is the function to do many apply on the dataframe

```
def Do_Compute(df):
  df['E_Det']=df['E'].apply(TrouverLesTest)
  df['E_Det_vs']=df['E'].apply(TrouverLesTest)
  return df
```

```
parallelize_dataframe(df2, Do_Compute)
```

output:

```
A   B   C           D       E       F   E_Det   E_Det_vs
0   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 3   test    foo True    True
1   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 4   train   foo False   False
2   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 2   test    foo True    True
3   1.0 2013-01-02  1.0 5   train   foo False   False
```

**My question :**  *How to compute the dataframe df2 more quickly when using the function Do_Compute(df) in spark ?*

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do a simple computation as in your question, you can do

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'E_Det',
    F.when(F.col('E') == 'test', F.lit(True)).when(F.col('E') == 'train', F.lit(False))
)
```

Note that if you're using Spark, you don't need to mess around with the multithreading library. Spark is a parallel computation framework by nature.

For more general usage of Python/pandas functions in Spark, you can use `mapInPandas`:

```
def Do_Compute(iterator):
    for df in iterator:
        df['E_Det']=df['E'].apply(TrouverLesTest)
        df['E_Det_vs']=df['E'].apply(TrouverLesTest)
        yield df

df2 = df.mapInPandas(Do_compute, schema)
```

where you need to provide the schema of the resulting dataframe. e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = df.schema.add(StructField('E_Det', BooleanType())).add(StructField('E_Det_vs', BooleanType()))
```

See the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.mapInPandas) for further details on its usage.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer so how to do compute on the dataframe with the function Do_Compute(df)

Comment: @hugo you can use `mapInPandas` as in my edited answer.

Comment: My dataframe  a pandas dataframe, df.schema does not work

Comment: @hugo I thought you said you want to use spark?

Comment: Yes I want to use spark but my dataframe is in pandas how to use "df.mapInPandas(Do_compute, schema)" if df is in pandas I got the error " 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mapInPandas'

Comment: @hugo you can convert to a spark dataframe first, e.g. using `sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)` where `spark` is the `SparkSession`

Comment: I still have this error : 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'mapInPandas'

Comment: @hugo it's only available in Spark 3. You need to update spark to use that functionality if your spark version is too old.

Comment: i have this error:  AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "E_Det" among (A, B, C, D, E, F);